# How do I get the correct hash values when reading a .txt wordlist line-by-line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, md5, argparse

I'm trying to build a Python3.x script that reads a .txt wordlist and convert the word on every line to its hashed equivalent however when I execute this script it produces a wrong hash.

Hope you guys can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here..

## Output

```
Arguments passed to the program:
Namespace(inputHashType=['md5'], verbose=True, 
    wordlist=_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\Mikael\\Desktop\\wordlist.txt' mode='rt' encoding='utf-8')
Verbose is set to: True

correct hash:  b61a6d542f9036550ba9c401c80f00ef
Line 1:  PT: tests      As hash: a58c6e40436bbb090294218b7d758a15
```

## Example of inputfile:

```
tests
tests1
tests2
```

## Source Code

```
import argparse
import sys
from Crypto.Hash import MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Hash production')
parser.add_argument('-v', action='store_true', dest='verbose', default=False, help='Print attempts')
parser.add_argument('-t', nargs=1, dest='inputHashType', help='Hash type')
parser.add_argument('-d', nargs='?', dest='wordlist', type=argparse.FileType('rt', encoding='utf-8'), default=sys.stdin, help='Dictionary (as file)')
args =  parser.parse_args()

inputHashType = ''.join(map(str, args.inputHashType)) # Formats args list as string
inputHashType.lower()

if inputHashType == 'md5':
    htype = MD5.new()

try:
    if args.verbose:
        with args.wordlist as file:
            line = file.readline()
            cnt = 1
            while line:
                word = line.encode('utf-8').rstrip()
                hashed = htype.update(word)
                hashed = htype.hexdigest()
                print("Line {}:  PT: {}      As hash: {}".format(cnt, line.strip(), hashed))
                line = file.readline()
                cnt += 1
    else:
        break
except:
    print('Error')
```

Comment: a [mcve] would be more useful: we don't care about argparse, we don't have your input file. minimal means smallest possible amount of code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The `while` loops in the `if args.verbose/else` are almost identical apart from the `strip` v `rstrip`. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @doctorlove Yes, it was but i have removed this part of code from my question because there was too much unnecessary code.

Comment: An example of the input file may help. Is it guaranteed to be only one word a line?

Comment: @Guy - The input file only contain one word on each line.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Probably, your input file is not what it appears to be, and there are some invisible (bad) characters that aren't stripped. Have you tried printing the actual bytes? You're printing `line.strip()`, but not `word`; the latter variable is your actual input to your hashing algorithm, so that should be the first step to verify that it is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in the `try` block of your code, you're re-using the `MD5` hash evaluator for each new line by the `update()` method.  This does not calculate the hash value for that input string, but accumulates the input and evaluates the hash of accumulated strings up to that point.

It's easy to see this is what is happening by using `md5sum`:

```
$ echo -n 'tests' | md5sum
b61a6d542f9036550ba9c401c80f00ef  -    # Identical to your 1st output line
$ echo -n 'teststests' | md5sum         # This is what you're calculating
a58c6e40436bbb090294218b7d758a15  -    # Identical to your 2nd output line.
```

To evaluate the hash value for each new input, you'll need to re-initialize a new `MD5` instance by calling the `new()` method.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but how do i stop the MD5 evaluator from accumulating the input?

Comment: @MikaelFangel sorry about the omission. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks! This will definitely solve my problem when i figure out how to implement it.